# What does this KeyError mean and how can I solve it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keyerror

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("output.csv")


df["Output_before"] = df["Output(kWh)"].shift(-1)
df["Output_changes"] = (df["Output(kWh)"] / df["Output_before"]) - 1 

df["Output_before"] = df["Output(kWh)"].shift(-1)

df["Output_changed"] = (df["Output(kWh)"] / df["Output_before"]) -1

df = df.dropna()

changes = df["Output(kWh)"]

# input shape: (number_of_train_examples, sequence_length, input_dim)
import numpy as np

X = []
Y = []

for i in range (0, len(changes) - 20):
    Y.append(changes[i])
    X.append(np.array(changes[i+1:i+21][::-1]))

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 20, 1)
Y = np.array(Y)
```

The KeyError is '191' and I don't understand why. 
I tested the same code with an other dataset and it worked.
Is there an issue with my dataset?
In the attachment is a picture of the error code. 
KeyError.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9iuj.jpg)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Comment: seems like you're indexing `changes[i+1:i+21]` beyond the size of `changes`

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: When the error occurs  what is the value of `i` and how many rows are there in `changes`?

Comment: It means you are trying to access `changes[191]` and that index is higher than `len(changes) - 1`.

Comment: How can I solve it?

Comment: There are 516 rows in changes